# HTML, JQuery button on click to specific function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a piece of script that changes the background on click. But when I click anything even the screen, the background changes. I would like only the button to change
the background image. I just can't seem to code it properly in jquery. Any help is most appreciated. Thanks

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <style>
      body 
      {
      background:url(Pic/jungle.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
      -webkit-background-size: cover;
      -moz-background-size: cover;
      -o-background-size: cover;
      background-size: cover;
      }
   </style>
   <body>
      <button class="color" style="background-image: url('Pic/changebackground.png'); width:60px; height: 50px;background-repeat:no-repeat;background-color: transparent;border:none;"></button>
      <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
      <script>
         $(document).ready(function () {
              var rotate = 0;
              var colors = ["url('Pic/hi.jpg')", "url('Pic/jungle.jpg')"];
              $('body').on("click", function () {

                  $(this).css({
                      'background-image': colors[rotate]
                  });
                  rotate++;
                  if (rotate >= 2) {
                      rotate = 0;
                  }     

              });   
          });

      </script>
```

Comment: i tried that and used  a div id and put $("NameOfID").on but it didnt work. Maybe I should have added that part in my explanation before people decide to down vote me

Comment: `$("#NameOfID")`, not `$("NameOfID")`, don't forget the #.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to tie the event to the button, then select the body and perform the css manipulation to that. You're code would look like this:

```
$('button').on("click", function () {
    $('body').css({
        'background-image': colors[rotate]
    });
});
```